# Room cannot verify the data integrity in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

> MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private AppDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Database creation
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "Medimap-db").build();
//        Profile profile=new Profile("rajitha","12-2-345","male","no 345","test med","test emergency","testurl");
//        db.profileDao().insert(profile);
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new DatabaseAsync().execute();


    }

    private class DatabaseAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //Perform pre-adding operation here.
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //Let's add some dummy data to the database.
            Profile profile = new Profile("rajitha", "12-2-345", "male", "no 345", "test med", "test emergency", "testurl");
            db.profileDao().insert(profile);


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //To after addition operation here.
        }
    }

}
```

> AppDatabase class

```
   @Database(entities = {Profile.class, Medicine.class}, version = 1)
    public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract ProfileDao profileDao();
        public abstract MedicineDao medicineDaoDao();
    }
```

> ProfileDao

```
@Dao
public interface ProfileDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM profile")
    List<Profile> getAll();

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
//    List<Profile> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND "
//            + "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
//    User findByName(String first, String last);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Profile... profiles);

    @Insert
    void insert(Profile profile);

    @Delete
    void delete(Profile profile);
}
```

> Here I got an error after the first run of the app. It seems like the app is trying to create DATABASE once again, but there already is an existing one so they suggested to change the version code. My requirement is that I only need to insert a new data set. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance. Here is the logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

Comment: If you are changing the database schema (ie either entity or something else) then you have to increase version in this line `@Database(entities = {Profile.class, Medicine.class}, version = 1)`

Comment: try this..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity/44197403#44197403

Comment: See I need to enter data to profile table.So I'm not going to change schema of the table.

Comment: See I need to enter data to profile table.So I'm not going to change schema of the table.

Comment: This question is almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity Check the first answer to that question and you will have a much more complete answer that handles several scenarios (like when this error happens and you have your app already on production).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're only developing the application at the moment, it means that you are not on Production and uninstalling the app from device and install it again will work as required.

Comment: In some devices sometimes it need device to restart.

Comment: On Oreo, it doesn't seem to go away no matter what I try.

Comment: Confirmed, in Oreo, it doesn't go away.

Comment: When running in emulator, I had to uninstall and delete the app folders.

Answer (score 63):

#### Android 6.0+

For those of you who come across this now a days, simply uninstalling might not help and it will drive you nuts, so before you have to figure it out, let me share the issue: Google introduced the "autobackup" functionality in
Android 6.0, which brings back a DB when you reinstall. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)

You can simply add...

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false">
</app>
```

...to disable this functionality and you are good to go (now you can simply uninstall to delete the database).

Comment: is there any way to keeyp the `android:allowBackup=false` and not crashing?

Comment: this has never crashed for me, what does your crash report say?

Comment: Thank you @SimonMayrshofer . This is still relevant in 2023.

Comment: @EugeneP. :D happy to hear that!

Answer (score 17):

Increase the version:

```
@Database(entities = {EmployeeEntry.class}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
```

Took from
[link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929)

Answer (score 15):

**If you don't care about migrations when update entities:**

1. Increase database version
2. Add `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` method at the time of building database, e.g:

   Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase.class, "appdb.db") 
   .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
   .build();

Hope this help someone ;)

Answer (score 11):

There are 3 ways to fix this data integrity exception.

**1) If you don't want to increase your Database version and you can bear data loss**
Just clear your App data from App settings after installing new build in device and launch App again, it would work without data integrity exception

**2) If you can increase your Database version but still you can bear data loss**
If you want to make it seamless( no crash due to schema update), you can simply increase Database version (let say from 1 to 2) and mention Default migration strategy in Database Builder `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`. Then on installing this App, your previous DB data would clear up and you wouldn't get this data integrity exception.

**3) If you can increase your Database version and also want to save your previous data**
You need to increase your Database version(let say from 1 to 2) but also need to implement proper migrations logic (based on your lower version and higher version) in your App. Then on installing new version, you will not get this data integrity exception.
For migrations of Room you can read out [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) nice article written for migrations

For official documentation of Room migrations go to [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions)

Comment: In my case, first option is enough and it worked well. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, reinstalling didn't help and also I couldn't set `android:allowBackup:true` because one of the libraries I had used required it. So I went to Settings > Apps > My app, and cleared data and memory for that app. Problem gone;)

Comment: This is the answer for us. It drives us crazy over a solid day when my mate's codes work fine but my doesn't, both are from the same branch commit...

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Install new build

Step 2: Clear all app data from Settings.

Step 3: Open app ( will work fine now )

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `adb shell pm uninstall com.package.app` in your terminal to fully uninstall the app. After that, install it again and the error will disappear.