# error crash RoomCaused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: products.id (code 1555)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

product.kt

```
package com.store.bamboo.model.room

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

@Entity(tableName = "products")
data class Product(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String,
    @SerializedName("units")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "units") var units:Int,
    @SerializedName("price")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price") var price: Double,
    @SerializedName("off")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "off") var off: Double,
    @SerializedName("image")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image") var image: String
)
```

AppDatabase.kt

```
package com.store.bamboo.model.room

import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = arrayOf(Product::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun productDao(): ProductDao
}
```

Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
    Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
        (UNIQUE constraint failed: products.id (code 1555))
    #################################################################
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:281)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: products.id (code 1555)
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
    Caused By : Abort due to constraint violation.
        (UNIQUE constraint failed: products.id (code 1555))

Comment: Did you try follow the advice "increasing the version number"?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity

Comment: In this line **@Database(entities = arrayOf(Product::class), version = 1)**, change version to 2

Comment: I did this and changed the version to 2 but it was still an error

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are violating primary key uniqueness. So you got error:

> Error Code : 1555 (SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY) Caused By : Abort due
>   to constraint violation. (UNIQUE constraint failed: products.id (code
>   1555))

I found your data class has primary key its reference is "id". But you passing id through constructor. But are you sure every time you pass id as unique through constructor?? I think no. **So make sure you pass `id` as unique value.**