# Can't figure out the room database version error

Tags: android, android-room

This is the error I got,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity.  Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(RoomOpenHelper.java:135)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:115)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:411)
                                                                                at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:100)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
                                                                                at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:233)
```

My Database class is

```
@Database(entities = SliderImageModel.class, version = DbConfig.Version_SliderImage_84, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class SliderImageDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract SliderImageDao sliderImageDao();

    public static SliderImageDatabase INSTANCE;

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_84 = new Migration(DbConfig.Version_NewsAnnouncement_1, DbConfig.Version_SliderImage_84) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(SLIDERIMAGE);
        }
    };
    private static final Migration MIGRATION_2_84 = new Migration(DbConfig.Version_SchoolEvent_2, DbConfig.Version_SliderImage_84) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(SLIDERIMAGE);
        }
    };
```

Comment: uninstall the app and reinstall or update your database version.

Comment: this is not how you ask a question on SO though. please look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Room cannot verify the data integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity)

Comment: i had tried uninstalling the app / cache clear and also increased the version code

Comment: i did migrations like this  @Database(entities = SliderImageModel.class, version = DbConfig.Version_SliderImage_84, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class SliderImageDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract SliderImageDao sliderImageDao();

    public static SliderImageDatabase INSTANCE;

    private static final Migration MIGRATION_1_84 = new Migration(DbConfig.Version_NewsAnnouncement_1, DbConfig.Version_SliderImage_84) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(SLIDERIMAGE);
        }

Comment: please don't post your code in comments, instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58988255/edit) your original post to add it

Comment: i couldn't add this database build code in the post

Answer (score -1):

Try with below by increasing your version number as mentioned,

```
@Database(entities = pojo.class, exportSchema= false, version=2 )
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled