# Room database throwing error after reinstalling - Room cannot verify the data integrity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I am in the project development phase. So, I basically do not need migrations at this point in time. I had FirstTable before and SecondTable is the newly added one. I already had prepackaged db also. Below is the code used.

```
@Database(
    entities = [
        FirstTable::class,
        SecondTable::class
    ],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = true
)
abstract class MyDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        private const val databaseName = "my-db"
        private const val prepackagedDB = "prepackaged-db"

        fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyDatabase::class.java, databaseName) 
                .createFromAsset(prepackagedDB) 
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

I have also given `android:allowBackup="false"` in AndroidManifest.xml. I do not want to use `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` which clears my prepackaged db too.

I uninstalled the app in the emulator(API Level 29) and ran the app. I am getting this error.

I am not able to understand why reinstalling is causing this issue. Could someone let me know what I went wrong?

Comment: Try using curly brace while mentioning entities in the annotation. So, `entities = {
        FirstTable::class,
        SecondTable::class
    }`

Comment: Also, Please mention the error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity

Comment: @Vedant error is what I have mentioned in the question title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Room cannot verify the data integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197309/room-cannot-verify-the-data-integrity)

Comment: @RodrigoQueiroz no..

Comment: Maybe your prepackaged-db schema differs from your current one (maybe it doesn't include your SecondTable)? How exactly did you get this prepackaged db?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov Yes, you are right. My prepackaged DB doesn't contain that table. I am creating it on the go. That was a good hint. Let me put an empty table in my prepackaged DB and see. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @sergiytikhonov You were right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Included the new table(an empty one) in the prepackaged DB and then it's working fine.