# Setting android:allowBackup="false"

Tags: java, android

Does setting `android:allowBackup="false"` prevents application data stored on sqlite to be accessed from rooted devices?

I have read the answers in the [What is "android:allowBackup"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648373) where I didn't found a clear answer to my question.
I am asking explicitly about rooted device cases.

Comment: Rooted devices can access anything... That's kind of the point of being rooted

Comment: @NileshRathod and others, I am asking explicitly about rooted device, if you managed to read till the end.

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for your comment

Answer (score 4):

Basically "android:allowBackup" flag will let the system know whether to take backup of your application while taking the system backup. By default, it is set to "true". If you don't want to participate your application in data backup/restore infrastructure then you can simply make it false.

Please refer [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#allowbackup)

Now coming to your question, this flag is nothing to do with your application database.

Happy Coding!

Comment: "...this flag is nothing to do with your application database."  Really?!  Happy Coding you too!