# How to force delete application data on uninstall (Android)?

Tags: android

There is a strange function in some Android devices (at least Galaxy S7): they restore data (for example the SQLite database) when the application is reinstalled. This behavior interrupts my app because the data is supposed to be deleted during uninstallation.

How can I force Android to completely delete all that data when the app is manually uninstalled?

Comment: use `android:allowBackup="false"` in the manifest file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35296675/1025070

Answer (score 5):

You have to disable the backup from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:allowBackup="false"
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
```

**N.B**: If you use any third party `library` that use `android:allowBackup="true"` then it conflicts and give error. To resolve this and `override` the setting you also have to add `tools:replace="android:allowBackup"`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a privacy concern. It is recommended to disallow users to backup an app if it contains sensitive data. Having access to backup files (i.e. when `android:allowBackup="true"`), it is possible to modify/read the content of an app even on a non-rooted device.

Solution - use `android:allowBackup="false"` in the manifest file.

Read this post to know more about this: https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/android-hacking-security-part-15-hacking-android-apps-using-backup-techniques/

Original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475593/5304075

Answer (score 1):

For your question, it's simple. Just add the below line to your app's manifest file's `<application>` tag.

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

This makes the app's data not to be saved when it is uninstalled.