# How to backup/restore files on Android 10 or higher?

Tags: android, mediastore

I have implemented db file backup and restore function
As of Android 10, you must use mediastore
If you save the backup file in the downloads folder, delete the app and reinstall it
I can't access that file

Is there a way to access the previously created files after reinstalling the app in the mediastore for Android 10 or higher?

How to implement the restore function if the previously created file cannot be accessed?

Comment: Add ````android:allowBackup=true```` in your manifest. This will backup all your data on storage so that when user unsitall and install ur app again, all the data backed up will be restored within your app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "android:allowBackup"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648373/what-is-androidallowbackup)