# What is the best way to store large files created by my app in Android sdk 30?

Tags: android, android-11, file-access

My app creates large files of my own format. We used to save those on device memory but from sdk level 30 we can't access them anymore (it is too slow and complicated to use DocumentFiles).

Is there a way to store files in scoped storage that are not media files, that doesn't increase app memory and bog it down?

And I am also worried about files being deleted when a user uninstalls the app.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit: We used to store it on a folder on the phone memory that is accessible by the user via file browser. On Android 11 we can't do that so the files would have to move to scoped storage i.e. Android/data//files

Is there another storage location that an app can access on Android 11 that won't be deleted after app uninstall?

Comment: You said `scoped storage`, I think you can check this document: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648373/what-is-androidallowbackup refer this

Comment: `We used to save those on device memory` ??? Where ever you save them its always on device memory if not not on removable micro sd card. So what is it that you wanna tell us but did not?

Comment: `Is there a way to store files in scoped storage` ?? Scoped storage is no storage location. So what is it that you wanna ask but formulated wrong.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. English is not my first language. Please see my edits. What do you mean by "scoped storage is no storage location"?